# In Angular, how do you use a Route to go to a completely different URL? In other words how do you turn off matching?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a front-end Angular application in which I need to have a menu item that goes to a completely different website.

For example, suppose I have a website with a URL of

https://scn-webdev.myserver.com/myapp

And I need to have a menu item in the app go to the completely different website of

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

If I do something like this:

```
export const appRoutes: Route    
{ 
    redirectTo: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' 
}
```

It sends me to a url of:
https://scn-webdev.myserver.com/myapp/undefined

If I do something like this:

```
export const appRoutes: Route
{ 
    path: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' 
}
```

It sends me to a url of:
https://scn-webdev.myserver.com/myapp/https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

I've tried messing with the pathMatch parameter - setting it to 'full', 'prefix', and a few other things.

No matter what, it doesn't seem to want to just re-direct to a completely different URL without
retaining any of the url path for the current page.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use an `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">` within the menu?

Comment: Just use an <a> tag with an HREF set to the external URL - ah, beaten to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this for external links:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
```

where you can also do:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
   <li><a [href]="menuItem.externalLink"></li>
<ul>
```

if you want to do it dynamically

The Router is not made to direct to external routes.

Answer (score 0):

For the above scenario in my view you shouldnt be using angular router, simple use window.location.href = ' [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask%27) or a simple a href tag

Comment: Thanks - I definitely appreciate both of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

as the 'appRoutes' could suggest, it refers to the routes of the app.

But in this case, you would like to link to an URL that is not part of your app and is not part of your routes.
Sometimes the answer is just in a name of variable or function ;)

At this point you can easily use an old and friendly tag:

```
<a href="https://myLink.com">
```